# VB6 Error 50003 Unexpected Error: is the solution to re-register DLLs?

Tags: vb6, dll

If the above error is shown during the execution of a VB6 app, is the solution to re-register DLLs that it might be accessing at the time?

Or is this an issue about versions of DLLs not being correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've seen this error before with controls (ocx).  It can usually be solved by recompiling the program with the latest version.

If that's not the issue, I find a good brute-force method to clean the registry and check you have the correct version installed is to simply delete the dll in question (or just rename it) and then use a utility like [CClean](http://www.piriform.com/ccleaner) to delete the orphaned entry.  I admit it's a sledgehammer to crack a nut.

Answer (score 9):

Or you might have added an Icon to your application and is not compatible with the OS version just like what happened to me.

Comment: Another strange but similar icon-related problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54136587/3195477

Answer (score 2):

Change the icons in your form.

Comment: This was the issue for me. I removed the form icon and the binary worked fine after that.

Answer (score 0):

You might check the exe/dlls with a tool like Dependency Walker to see if there is a missing component:
http://download.cnet.com/Dependency-Walker/3000-2086_4-10052198.html